# Generate peak in channel2 on signal change in channel1 in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am monitoring a signal (channel1) in my simulink model. Whenever it changes I would like to generate a triangular peak in another channel (channel2). Before and after that peak the signal in channel2 should be zero.

So far I achieved to generate a single triangular peak by integrating the output of a step-block. But I fail to generate the peak at the time when signal1 changes. I can monitor the change with an DetectChange-block but I don't know how to trigger the step-block to go off at the right time. I played a bit with triggered or enabled subsystems but so far I can't get my head around it.

So any help is appreciated

[image: Genarate single peak triangle signal on signal change]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a solution. With this whenever signal1 changes I get exactly two triangular shaped peaks (top and bottom) on signal2. The peak starts directly at the time when the change happens.

In the underneath picture I use a step-Block to change Signal1 at 1.5s. So the peak in Signal2 also starts at 1.5s.

[image: Simulink Block-Sheet]